# Is there a Mongoose method to save multiple documents, but only when all success

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, atomic

I have an array of documents, but I only want to save them when every document will success. Is there a Method from Mongoose?

Something like:

```
Insert el[0] - success
Insert el[1] - success
Insert el[2] - fail
Delete el[1]
Delete el[0]
```

Comment: Afaik mongoose does not support transactions.

Comment: This tutorial can help you: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-implement-transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use transactions to implement this. Here's an example from the docs:

```js
let session = null;
return Customer.createCollection().
  then(() => Customer.startSession()).
  then(_session => {
    session = _session;
    session.startTransaction();
    return Customer.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session: session });
  }).
  then(() => Customer.create([{ name: 'Test2' }], { session: session })).
  then(() => session.abortTransaction()).
  then(() => Customer.countDocuments()).
  then(count => assert.strictEqual(count, 0)).
  then(() => session.endSession());
```

You can use `abortTransaction` to rollback queries in case of error.

Read more here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html
https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

Comment: Thank you, did you know if the _id on a .findOne().session() will be passed along?

Comment: @JanneckLange I didn't get you.